# sed error of "no such file or directory" in setting up bashrc

Tags: bash, sed

Sorry to ask a question that might seem naive to some experienced people. I am not good at Linux, when trying to modify ~/.bashrc as below:

```
sed -i s/'history -cw'//g .bash_logout
```

when I source it, I receive an error saying:

> sed: can't read .bash_logout: No such file or directory

What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no file with the name .bash_logout in the directory you are currently in. Use `pwd` command.

Comment: The error literally means *"can't read .bash_logout: No such file or directory"*. Error messages are usually pretty good (and have gotten much better over the past decade)

Comment: When specifying scripts on the command line for any command, surround the script in quotes, don't start and end the quotes half way through the command! Your command should syntactically be written as `'s/history -cw//g'`, not `s/'history -cw'//g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't using the path. If you were trying to just delete the line then use:

```
sed -i s/'history -cw'//g .bash_logout  #if I am in the current dir
```

or

```
sed -i s/'history -cw'//g ${HOME}/.bash_logout
```

or

```
sed -i s/'history -cw'//g ~/.bash_logout
```

or

```
sed -i s/'history -cw'//g /path/to/.bash_logout
```

To ADD to the file consider the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep -q "history -cw" .bash_logout ;then
        echo "lets add this baby"
        echo "history -cw" >> .bash_logout
else
        echo "it is already there, don't add .."
fi
```

Note: your current issue is that you are not specifying the path to where the file is located. Be as explicit as possible:

This script sets the value to the full path and also checks if that file exists first before trying to do anything :

```
LOGOUT="/home/user/.bash_logout"
if [ ! -f "$LOGOUT" ] ;then
        echo "file not found"
        exit
fi

if ! grep -q "history -cw" "$LOGOUT" ;then
        echo "lets add this baby"
        echo "history -cw" >> "$LOGOUT"
else
        echo "it is already there, don't add .."
fi
```

Comment: @EdMorton I think you meant to post to the other person and not mine.

Comment: Gotcha , good catch, I see what you are saying now ... I made a minor update